# Ajax'ed file field doesn't find the form constructor function on rebuild

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm manually printing the user profile form in a block using:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
$form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);
```

That works great for displaying and submitting the form.

The form has an image field to add a picture. When I try to upload the picture through Ajax, I get a PHP notice that `drupal_retrieve_form()` is missing the form constructor function (`user_profile_form()`), and the image field isn't being shown anymore.

I'm guessing the image field's Ajax doesn't know about the user.pages file that I included, and can't find the form.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include file by using the `$form_state['build_info']['files']` array.

For example:

```
$form_state['build_info']['files'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'user') . '/user.pages.inc';
```